# how to erase element in 2d vector?

Tags: c++

I want to delete an element in a `2d vector`, say `[1][1]` in `Field`, which is a `4x5 vector`

I tried

```
Field.erase([1][1]);
```

I know that for a `1d vector`, I would just do

```
Field.erase (Field.begin()+1)
```

but what about for `2d vectors`?

Answer (score 7):

```
Field[1].erase(Field[1].begin() + 1);
```

That's how you erase an element.  But by your comments, that's not what you really want.  What you actually want is to clear the value of the element to it's default value.  For that:

```
Field[1][1] = Card();
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Doing the above will delete one element from 'Field', making its second row have 4 instead of 5 elements.

But what do I do if I just want to delete the content in that element thus restore it as an empty element (to keep the 2nd row with 5 elements)? ('Field' was originally an empty 4x5 vector since it was written as
    vector< vector<Card> > Field(4, vector<Card>(5));
)

I was thinking of doing something like
       Field[1].insert(Field[1].begin()+1);

Comment: @MK: What does it mean for an element to be empty?

Comment: @MK: When you write `vector< vector<Card> > Field(4, vector<Card>(5));` - Field is certainly not empty.  It contains 20 elements, so I have no idea how you are using the word 'empty' here.

Comment: I meant that I want to restore the deleted element in row 2 so that it is not initialized. I just want to delete the VALUE of the element Field[1][1], not the actual element itself

Comment: @MK: So you just want it to have it's default value?  `Field[1][1] = Card();` (note, this is *instead* of the answer I originally gave, not in addition to it)

Comment: @MK: In reality though, you're not deleting the value.  That doesn't make any sense in C++.  Every object has a value.  It might make sense if the elements are pointers, and you want to delete the object that the pointer points to, but the elements themselves(the pointers) still have a value.